# Shell script to properly align columns

Tags: bash, shell

I have a (3-columns) TAB-delimited file, such as:

```
activity_log    manager Manager
reserve_rm_hreserver_rm_log manager Manager
mo  apprv_mgr1  Approving Manager
wrview  manager Manager
```

I'd like to get columns correctly aligned; in this case:

```
activity_log                  manager      Manager
reserve_rm_hreserver_rm_log   manager      Manager
mo                            apprv_mgr1   Approving Manager
wrview                        manager      Manager
```

No doubt this is doable with awk, by scanning the longest string in every column, and using that for formatting the column printing.  I could do that.

But I'm sure there must be a one-liner to do that much more easily. Am I right?

Comment: `column -t file` should do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ column -t myfile.txt
```

you can use different chars to fill (`man column` is your friend)

Comment: With -s '<TAB character>', that's what I was after. Thx a lot!